# How to store an image in the database using Angular 4 and Spring

Tags: spring, angular, rest

I'm using Angular 4 for the Front-end and Spring for the Back-end and I wanna store a user which contains an image in my database.
As i know the type **Blob** exists in **Angular 4** but it doesn't in Spring, and the type **byte** exists in **Spring** but it doesn't in Angular 4.
How can I transfer my image from the Front-end to the Back-end using REST API.

This is my entity:

```
import java.sql.Blob;
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_OAUTH", schema = "OAUTH")
public class UserOauth implements java.io.Serializable {
 private long idUser;
 private String username;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String adrEmail;
 private int isAdAccount;
 private Date lastConnection;
 private String password;
 private boolean enabled;
 private int attempts;
 private Blob photo;

@Lob
@Column(name = "PHOTO", length = 10000000)
public Blob getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}
```

This is my DTO :

```
public class UserDTO implements java.io.Serializable {

 private long idUser;
 private String username;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String adrEmail;
 private int isAdAccount;
 private Date lastConnection;
 private String password;
 private boolean enabled;
 private Blob photo;
```

This is my web service :(it works normally before adding the photo):

```
// Add a new user;
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public UserDTO addUser(@RequestBody final UserDTO user) throws Exception {
    return modelMapper.map(userService.saveUser(modelMapper.map(user, UserOauth.class)), UserDTO.class);
}
```

And finally my Typescript :

```
export class UserData {
  public  idUser: number;
  public  username: string;
  public  firstName: string;
  public  lastName: string;
  public  adrEmail: string;
  public  isAdAccount: boolean;
  public  lastConnection: Date;
  public  password: string;
  public  enabled: boolean;
  public  photo:Blob;
}
```

If there is any rectifications please let me know.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Try convert to base64 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: @Swoox what about the image type in the database, it won't be a problem ? Because i wanna store it as BLOB

Comment: this might [help](http://javasampleapproach.com/frontend/angular/angular-4-uploadget-multipartfile-tofrom-spring-boot-server)

Answer (score 1):

If you are really in the case when it makes a sense to store the images in the database, then you can you use LOB datatype:

```
// File content
@Lob
private Blob image;
```

On the Front-end use FormData to pass the file to the Back-end using REST API, see a sample [here](https://github.com/alextunyk/fileupload-metadata/blob/b7e0f8e251f82c203486894ea45ec9d0b041f878/web/src/App.js#L53)

P.S.
You might probably want to store an image in the file system and keep its path in the database. Please see [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay).

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript/ Angular you can declare your field like the following: `img: File;`

Your DTO in your RestController in Spring should use `private final byte[] img;` and finally your Entity also

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "IMG", length = 10000000)
private byte[] img;
```

Comment: what about the initialization in the DTO ?

Comment: You need to map from your Entity to the DTO of course.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Spring Data then [Spring Content JPA](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) is a lot easier than using @Lob directly and writing your own @Controller to handle multipart/form-data POSTs.

Add the following dependencies:

> pom.xml

```
   <!-- Java API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-jpa-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.11</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- REST API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.11</version>
   </dependency>
```

Add the following attributes to your UserOauth entity so that content can be associated with it.

> UserOAuth.java

```
@Entity
public class UserOAuth {

   ...existing fields...

   @ContentId
   private String contentId;

   @ContentLength
   private long contentLength = 0L;

   // if you have rest endpoints
   @MimeType
   private String mimeType;

   // no need for Blob
```

Create a `ContentStore` (the equivalent of a JpaRepository for BLOBs):

> UsersOAuthContentStore.java

```
@StoreRestResource(path="usersPhoto")
public interface UsersPhotoContentStore extends ContentStore<UserOAuth, String> {
}
```

(I assume you have the pre-requisite beans for database connectivity).

When you run your application Spring Content will see the `UsersPhotoContentStore` interface and the `spring-content-jpa` dependency and inject a JPA implementation of this interface for you.  It will also see the `spring-content-rest` dependency and add an @Controller implementation that forwards GET, PUT, POST and DELETE REST requests onto `UsersPhotoContentStore` as well.   This saves you from having to write either.  REST endpoints will be available at `/usersPhotos` so...

`curl -X POST -F "image=@/home/user1/Desktop/photo.jpg" /usersPhotos/{userOAuthId}`

will upload photo.jpg and associate it with your entity.  And:

`curl /usersPhotos/{userOAuthId}` will fetch it again.

HTH